# How to programatically open the android support library action bar overflow menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow, android-support-library

I'm using the android support compat action bar library to support 2.2 and higher.

Im able to show the menu, and one of my buttons is a overflow button (3 dots).

When it is clicked, I want to show the overflow menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            super.onBackPressed();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_overflow:
            openOptionsMenu();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I have this, but it is not working.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:sord.ids_connect="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_overflow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_secure"
        android:title="@string/action_overflow"
        sord.ids_connect:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Comment: could you share you menu.xml

Answer (score 1):

Well the basic idea behind `overflow` menu is that, options that are not important are collected and placed into it by default. You do not have to create an overflow menu by yourself. If you put your item's `showAsAction="never"` it will automatically be placed in the overflow menu.

For e.g.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_about"/>
```

all of these because they have `showAsAction="never"` will be placed onto the overflow menu automatically.

And in your switch statement you could simply declare:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        super.onBackPressed();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        //something
        break;
case R.id.action_refresh:
    //something
    break;
...
}
```

and so on. But if there is a hardware menu button, the `overflow` will not appear. For this you can refer to the [following](http://www.vivekbhusal.com/node/14).